# signin form with ajax and php

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

I'm changing sign in form on my site to use ajax. its just basically to check whether username and password are correct.But its not working at all it refreshes and nothing happens, can anyone see where I'm gong wrong in the code?

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="content">
      <h1>Login Form</h1>
        <form id="form1" name="form1" action="testform.php" method="post">
           <p><label for="username">Username: </label>
           <input type="text" name="username" id="username" /></p>
           <p><label for="password">Password: </label>
           <input type="password" name="password" id="password" /></p>
           <p><input type="submit" id="login" name="login" /></p>
        </form>
  <div id="message"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
<script type="text/javascript"
src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>   
$(document).ready(function() {

   $("#login").click(function() {

   var action = $("#form1").attr('action');
   var form_data = {
       username: $("#username").val(),
       password: $("#password").val(),
       is_ajax:
   };

   $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: action,
           data: form_data,
           success: function(response)
           {
              if(response == 'success')
                  $("#form1").slideUp('slow', function() {
                     $("#message").html("<p class='success'>logged in!</p>");
                  });
         else
           $( "#message").html("<p class='error'>Invalid username and/orpassword</p>");
           }
      });
      return false;
   });
});
</script>

<?php
   $is_ajax = $_REQUEST['is_ajax'];

  if(isset($is_ajax) && $is_ajax)
 {
     $username = $_REQUEST['username'];
     $password = $_REQUEST['password'];

    if($username == 'to_difine' && $password == 'to_difine')
  {
     echo "success";
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: are you checking for any errors?  does is_ajax at least need a value?  are you logging to see if the callback is executing?

Comment: `<input type="button" id="login" name="login" />`

Comment: Try making your login button not a `submit` or use `event.preventDefault()` in your onClick function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problems:**

1. Ajax request is returning the entire html page.
2. tag is out of order (invalid html).

**Corrections:**

1. Move the PHP code to the top of the file.
2. Add `exit;` to the php inside `if is_ajax` so the rest of the html is not returned.
3. Move `<script type="text/javascript">` below the jquery script.

Working [example](http://playground.zaplabs.com/sandbox/qa/stackexchange/stackoverflow/14246623/testform.php) and [source](http://playground.zaplabs.com/sandbox/qa/stackexchange/stackoverflow/14246623/testform.php.source).

Comment: Wow, you really nailed it. I really appreciate the help I was set to give up. I can't thank you enough :D